# Cannot get reference id by using underscore(product_order) on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, reference, foreign-keys, migration

Create Model using:

```
rails g model Product product_name:string
rails g model ProductCategory category_name:string

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product_category
end

class ProductCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end
```

And How to reference the category id(ProductCategory) into product?
And I do and edit migration below:

```
class AddProductCategoryToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    product_category = ProductCategory.create! category_name: "No category"
    add_reference :products, :product_category, foreign_key: true, default: product_categories_id
  end
end
```

After that i run rake db:migrate and got error:

```
== 20160716050030 AddCourseCategoryToCourses: migrating =======================
-- course_categories_id()
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined local variable or method `course_categories_id' for #<AddCourseCategoryToCourses:0x007fabfd2667d0>
```

Comment: run a migration like: `rails g migration AddColumnProductCategoryIdToProduct product_category_id:integer` and you're good to go.

Comment: @Emu okay I will try it, thank you